# How to insert multiple rows in php with two data is not in the table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have a problem inserting the multiple row from my table to my database. Ill show picture of my UI. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1okJB.png

There are 5 column that I will insert into my database Barcode,Description and QTY is in the table that I want to insert and the two data is outside the table,or not on the table e.g username and customer_id. Its printed on the other part of my UI.

I tried this ajax code but nothing happen.

```
$(document).on('click','.Enter',function(e){
    var user = [];
    var product = [];
    var customer = [];
    var quantity = [];
    $('input .user').each(function(){
        user.push($(this).text());
    });
    $('tableData tr td .barcode').each(function(){
        product.push($(this).text());
    });
    $('select .customer_id').each(function(){
        customer.push($(this).text());
    });
    $('tableData tr td .qty').each(function(){
        quantity.push($(this).text());
    });
    $.ajax({
        url:"insert_sales.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{user:user, product:product, customer:customer, quantity:quantity},
        success: function(data){
             alert(user[0]);
        },
     })
});
```

This is part of my HTML file.

```
<input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>" class="user" />
<select class="customer_id" name="customer" style='cursor:pointer'>
<?php  
     if(mysqli_num_rows($show)>0){
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($show)) {
?>
     <option value="<?php echo $row['customer_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['firstname'];?>
     </option>

<table id="table2">
<thead>
     <tr class='text-center'>
         <th>Barcode</th>
         <th>Description</th>
         <th>Price</th>
         <th>Unit</th>
         <th>Qty</th>
         <th>Sub.Total</th>
         <th>Action</th>
     </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tableData">
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is my insert_product.php file.

```
if(isset($_POST['user'])){
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $product = $_POST['products'];
    $customer = $_POST['customer'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $query = '';
    for($count = 0; $count<count($user); $count++){ 
        $user_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $user[$count]);
    $product_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $user[$count]);
    $customer_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $user[$count]);
    $quantity_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $user[$count]);
    if($user_clean != '' && $product_clean != '' && $customer_clean != '' && $quantity!= ''){
        $query = "INSERT INTO sales(username,product_id,customer_id,quantity)         VALUES('$user_clean',$product_clean,$customer_clean,$quantity_clean)";
    } 
}
if ($query != ''){
    if(mysqli_multi_query($db,$query)){
        echo "Item Inserted"
    }else{
        echo "Error";
    }
}else{
    echo "No Product";
}
}
```

Hope someone can help me about this one. I'd put an alert in ajax to know if the it passes to the code. There's no insert happening even though it passes to the alert.

Comment: There is no reasons to loop for a single HTML input (the `user` field), your user array will have only one value. But your grid can have multiple values. I don't think your logic can work if `user` array and `product` array don't match the same number of values. The same is for `customer`. You can try to remove the 2 `$().each` for `user` and `customer` and include `user.push($('input .user').text());` and `customer.push($('select .customer_id').text());` within the `each` of product.

Comment: Yeah. I beleive so. You mean inside the `each` product?

Comment: It returns empty array as I fetch the user

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Got it now. Big thank you.

Comment: You're welcome :)